# How to backup a [SQL Server] database if privileges are not present?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, backup-strategies

I have complete readonly access to a SQL Server Database. If I try to do a backup, I get the following message.

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_get_tape_devices', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

How can I take a backup and load this data into my local SQLServer Express Edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's the whole purpose of the SQL Server security model. Otherwise, any valid database user with read access would be able to backup a DB and restore it somewhere else in order to view sensitive data. The last thing anyone wants is users messing with the database engine.

Ask the DBA if you can obtain a copy, if permitted.

Comment: In my previous experience with Oracle, I was able to use a tool to store all the data to csv files by exporting them. and then use the same tool to import them to a local database. I had just read permissions on the database. I suppose I could write a tool to do that, instead.